# Selenium Webdriver : How to upload file using his relative path (javascript)

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm using *selenium webdriver with node.js (javascript ) under chrome.*

In some test , i have to upload a file using his relative path (my file to upload is in the same directory as the test file)

```
var fileInput = driver.findElement(webdriver.By.xpath('//*[@id="j_idt69:j_idt70_input"]'));
fileInput.sendKeys('./file.xml');
```

Strangely my test fails and i catch this error :

```
My error handler... WebDriverError: unknown error: path is not absolute:
```

In fact **am using a relative path** because my test is intented to be used in differents locations (VMs , jenkins , pc..).
and the absolute path isn't usefull for me.

**Suggestions ??**

Comment: how about finding out an absolute path dynamically and using it?

Comment: './file.xml' mewans your file is in project directory, is it so?

Comment: @kushal : yes it is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sendKeys` not support relative path as a argument.

Use `System.getProperty("user.dir")`  to get current working directory path.

```
 String path=System.getProperty("user.dir")
 fileInput.sendKeys(path+"\\file.xml");
```

Answer (score 5):

i have solved it this way :

detecting the absolute path dynamically and concat it with my file name :

**To detect the current directory path using this node command** :  `process.cwd()`

**the resulting path is :** `var path = process.cwd()+'/file.xml';`

**uploading action :**         `fileInput.sendKeys(path);`